# java.lang.VerifyError ,after datanucleus enahncement of classes

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, datanucleus

Im migrating my appengine-project from ant build to maven,Im using java 8 with JDO 2 and maven-datanucleus plugin for class enhancement and maven appengine-plugin 1.9.64. But on running the project,it gives `java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 15`
error. And if I run without datanucleus enhancement, it gives class not enhanced error.So I assume something wrong with datanucleus maybe..
Any suggestions would be appreciated thank you.

Problem accessing /home. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 15
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/project1/datastore/DbAppointment.jdoSetkey(Lcom/dhiti/care/server/datastore/DbAppointment;Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key;)V @4: ifnonnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0339 c700 0b2a 2bb5 032e a700 142a
    0x0000010: b403 392a 1017 2ab4 032e 2bb9 04cd 0500
    0x0000020: b1

```
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructionContext.createProxy(ConstructionContext.java:77)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:69)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
at com.project1.server.servlets.HomeServlet.<init>(HomeServlet.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2481)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1327)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-eb</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <plugins>


  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
                    <requireJavaVersion>
               <version>1.8</version>
        </requireJavaVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Perhaps your use of java 8 is later than the version of Java that the enhancer you're using caters for? That's what "stackmap frame" usually means, since its was introduced in later versions of Java. Update enhancer etc, to datanucleus v3.1+. But then google-appengine uses utterly ancient datanucleus, and isn't really datanucleus anyway

Comment: Apparently their documentation tells you how to use DataNucleus v3.x (unsupported, ancient also) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2

Comment: Thanks for all your help..I was able to find the working set of jars...

Answer (score 0):

For Google App Engine+Java 1.7 or 1.8+JDO2+Maven build project, set of jars that worked for me for datanucleus class enhancement are:

```
asm-5.0.4.jar
datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar
datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.jar
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.60.jar
```

I used manual enhancement of classes, through the command line.
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/enhancer.html#manual

```
java -cp target/classes/:lib/*  org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer  target/classes/com/project1/server/Entity/*.class
```

Where lib is a folder on containing above mentioned jars.

Comment: but then you're still using datanucleus-enhancer v1.1 and that does not handle stackmap frames either. So no, this is not an "answer"